# Why does my function with InkNode not work?

Tags: c#, function

I have a question from school, it supposed to be without all the generic things (I mean write things like `intnode<t>`). The question is to write a function that gets a list and a num, and removes the number from the list. and it just doesn't work and write me only 1->, expect all the outcome supposed to be.

My list:

```
IntNode list = new IntNode(4, new IntNode(1, new IntNode(9, new IntNode(2, new IntNode(72)))));
```

The code:

```
public static IntNode hamesh(IntNode list, int n)
{
    IntNode p = list;

    while (p != null)
    {
        if (p.GetValue() == n);
            list = Remove(list, p);

        p = p.GetNext();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Please help me :(

Comment: You need to rebuild the list when you find the node which should be deleted. Your current code will just return an original list.

Comment: how do i rebuild it?

Comment: By creating a new one via `new IntNode(...)` in recursive manner.